# Error receiving broadcast Intent when passing multiple points

Tags: android, android-intent, android-broadcast

I have read almost every post on SO regarding this and tried all solutions where I felt they were relative, but I still do not know why this is happening. Here is the LOgcat:

```
02-20 18:10:27.959: D/ProximityIntentReceiver(17636): entering receiver
02-20 18:10:27.959: W/dalvikvm(17636): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40adf9f0)
02-20 18:10:27.959: E/AndroidRuntime(17636): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-20 18:10:27.959: E/AndroidRuntime(17636): java.lang.RuntimeException: Error    receiving broadcast Intent { act=com.javacodegeeks.android.lbs.ProximityAlert flg=0x10 (has extras) } in com.example.newmaps.ProximityIntentReceiver@41550140
02-20 18:10:27.959: E/AndroidRuntime(17636):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:737)
02-20 18:10:27.959: E/AndroidRuntime(17636):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
02-20 18:10:27.959: E/AndroidRuntime(17636):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
02-20 18:10:27.959: E/AndroidRuntime(17636):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
02-20 18:10:27.959: E/AndroidRuntime(17636):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
02-20 18:10:27.959: E/AndroidRuntime(17636):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-20 18:10:27.959: E/AndroidRuntime(17636):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
02-20 18:10:27.959: E/AndroidRuntime(17636):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:817)
02-20 18:10:27.959: E/AndroidRuntime(17636):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
02-20 18:10:27.959: E/AndroidRuntime(17636):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-20 18:10:27.959: E/AndroidRuntime(17636): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
02-20 18:10:27.959: E/AndroidRuntime(17636):    at android.app.PendingIntent.getActivity(PendingIntent.java:195)
02-20 18:10:27.959: E/AndroidRuntime(17636):    at com.example.newmaps.ProximityIntentReceiver.onReceive(ProximityIntentReceiver.java:36)
02-20 18:10:27.959: E/AndroidRuntime(17636):    at android.app.LoadedApk$ReceiverDispatcher$Args.run(LoadedApk.java:728)
02-20 18:10:27.959: E/AndroidRuntime(17636):    ... 9 more
```

Here is the code within my Map class where I create a proximity alert along with the location listener:

```
    private void addProximityAlert(Double latitude, Double longitude, String poiName) {
     Bundle extras = new Bundle();
     extras.putString("name", poiName);
     extras.putInt("id", requestCode);
    Intent intent = new Intent(PROX_ALERT_INTENT);
    intent.putExtra(PROX_ALERT_INTENT, extras);
    PendingIntent proximityIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(Map.this, requestCode , intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    lm.addProximityAlert(
           latitude, // the latitude of the central point of the alert region
           longitude, // the longitude of the central point of the alert region
           POINT_RADIUS, // the radius of the central point of the alert region, in meters
           PROX_ALERT_EXPIRATION, // time for this proximity alert, in milliseconds, or -1 to indicate no                           expiration
           proximityIntent // will be used to generate an Intent to fire when entry to or exit from the alert region is detected
    );

    requestCode++;    
    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(PROX_ALERT_INTENT);
    registerReceiver(new ProximityIntentReceiver(), filter);
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Alert Added"+requestCode,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 }


    public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {


        Toast.makeText(Map.this, "Distance from Point:", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle b) {            
    }
    public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
    }
    public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {           
    }
    }
```

Here is the Proximity class:

```
public class ProximityIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1000;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

String key = LocationManager.KEY_PROXIMITY_ENTERING;

Boolean entering = intent.getBooleanExtra(key, false);

if (entering) {
    Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "entering receiver");
}
else {
    Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "exiting");
}

NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, null, 0);        

Notification notification = createNotification();        
notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, 
    "Proximity Alert!", "You are approaching: " +intent.getBundleExtra("deucalion0.ProximityAlert.").get("name"), pendingIntent);     
                                                                    //here-------------------------------------
notificationManager.notify( intent.getBundleExtra("deucalion0.ProximityAlert.").getInt("id"), notification);

}

private Notification createNotification() {
Notification notification = new Notification();

notification.icon = R.drawable.ic_launcher;
notification.when = System.currentTimeMillis();

notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_SHOW_LIGHTS;                

notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_VIBRATE;
notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS;
notification.defaults |= Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;

notification.ledARGB = Color.WHITE;
notification.ledOnMS = 300;
notification.ledOffMS = 1500;

return notification;
}}
```

When I run the application and open the map it is fine, but eventually crashes while the phone just sits there, I have no idea what it is doing, maybe it is something to do with the location listener? I would greatly appreciate some help to fix this as I am clueless at this point.

Comment: Did you try to use `applicationContext` when you register your `PendingIntent`? Also you can try to use `PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, null, 0);` with `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` flag

Comment: I am sorry I actually do not know how to answer your question I don't know what applicationContext is. Can you explain a bit more about what you think I should try please? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the LogCat:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.app.PendingIntent.getActivity(PendingIntent.java:195)
    at com.example.newmaps.ProximityIntentReceiver.onReceive(ProximityIntentReceiver.java:36)
```

The problem appears to be with this line when you call [`getActivity()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#getActivity%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.content.Intent,%20int%29):

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, null, 0);
```

which is confusing. The purpose of a PendingIntent is to start a Component, in this case an Activity, but you are passing a `null` Intent. What do you want this line of code to do?

Comment: I am not sure what I want it to do, I have been building this application from code I collected from multiple resources, and now I am completely lost. Sorry I cannot give you more info on this.

Comment: Do you want to start an Activity when you receive your proximity intent or just display a notification?

Comment: Just display a notification would be perfect! Thank you!!

Comment: Ok, I have another question first. When the user clicks on the Intent do you want to start your app, which is standard?

Comment: Basically my application is a map which has stored locations. When the map is set up I am creating an alert for each map marker, so the app is a map with map markers and when the user gets within 10 m or so of a marker then I want the alert to happen. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: Try changing `null` from the code about to an Intent for your Activity. I'll assume your activity is call `MainActivity`, so use: `PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, new Intent(context, MainActivity.class), 0);`

Comment: My activity is Map, I added it as you said with Map in there and again it crashes after a minute or two. As the app cycles through the map markers in the database and adds them to the map, I call the add proximity alert method passing each marker location and I get a toast for each one saying they were added. I set a couple of markers basically at my location so I should get an alert straight away. I am not sure what is going on. Would it help if I added my whole map class? I appreciate your patience!

Answer (score 2):

In ProximityIntentReceiver - change line

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, null, 0);
```

to

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
```

Comment: you should add also explanations regarding why that action should be taken and why the solution described by you would help.